# Generate different key on same run - RsaKeyPairGenerator C# BouncyCastle

Tags: c#, cryptography, bouncycastle

```
CryptoApiRandomGenerator randomGenerator = new CryptoApiRandomGenerator();
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(randomGenerator);

private void m ( ) {
    KeyGenerationParameters keyGenerationParameters = new KeyGenerationParameters(secureRandom, a);

    RsaKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
    keyPairGenerator.Init(keyGenerationParameters);
    a_method(keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair());
}
```

Why does the following code generates the same key when called twice but when the program restarts it generates a different key?

Example of same run (same instance but different times called m()):

public key A:

> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDhSUzd+38BxgCossYWUouldfKC+lKZuM2uymuz1ERebhQVYHtwBQT0T2yb07ksZgX5BeWThl3nzdNLdEOEztPj6lDxMb+jamrmInJE94t5xGIrN3dZSIKiVdfe4iztBLTMKH8V9s8rJIMGWAbr7ytBsGC1dOTluMnINhxpXGZIXQIDAQAB

public key B:

> MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDhSUzd+38BxgCossYWUouldfKC+lKZuM2uymuz1ERebhQVYHtwBQT0T2yb07ksZgX5BeWThl3nzdNLdEOEztPj6lDxMb+jamrmInJE94t5xGIrN3dZSIKiVdfe4iztBLTMKH8V9s8rJIMGWAbr7ytBsGC1dOTluMnINhxpXGZIXQIDAQAB

Comment: The two public keys are equal. I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: sorry it was unclear but those keys are generated on the same instance of the program but expected to be different and they're identical, why is that?

Comment: Where is the implementation of that `SecureRandom` class?

Comment: Since this is just a fragment that doesn't compile it's not possible to determine what the problem is.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, it uses the BouncyCastle.Crypto Library
the a_method prints both keys (private,public) in base64.

Comment: What is 'a' and 'a_method' ?

Answer (score 0):

Based only on your code snippet your random number is a global. Which means it's initialized once on startup and then stays the same. So you're feeding the same random number to your key generator every time. Quick fix is to move the two lines above function m() into the function.

Comment: SecureRandom generates a number, it's not a number.